# Storing the output of GetComputerNameA in a structure in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How would I go about storing the output of GetComputerNameA in a structure with a character array in c++? I don’t know, I think I have to use lpstrcpy?

I’m not too familiar with using objects in c++.

Comment: did you read [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea)? You don't store the output, you call the function and the function stores the output in a buffer. You only tell the function where to find the buffer

Comment: Yeah I read the manual. You’re right, the function stores the output in the buffer. But that’s what I’m having trouble with, I don’t know how to create an object for the buffer

Comment: @4p0cryph0n, what about an array of chars?

Answer (score 2):

As per [GetComputerNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea) documentation, char array size should be large enough to contain MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1 characters.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Computer
{
    char name[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1 ];
};


void main()
{
    DWORD cchComputerName = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    Computer computer = { 0 };

    if (!GetComputerNameA(&computer.name[0], &cchComputerName))
    {
        printf("Failed to get computer name, Error: %u\r\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Computer Name: %s\r\n", computer.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main` - As per C++ standard, `main` ideally should return `int`. With `main` you can omit return at the end - Compiler will add it for you. `int main` - Always!

Comment: `&computer.name[0]` can be simply `computer.name` since an array *decays* to a pointer to the 1st element: `GetComputerNameA(computer.name, &cchComputerName)`